# Using zhmCJK without the sim*.ttf fonts

Tags: fonts, cjk

I'm using texlive 2014 on linux and don't have the sim*.ttf fonts. I'd like to try out the zhmCJK package. The documentation seems to indicate that it requires those fonts. 
Is it possible to use the zhmCJK package without the sim*ttf fonts? What are the workaround if yes?

Answer (score 1):

No, `zhmCJK` does not restrict the font you use. `sim*.ttf` are only **examples** in the document. You can certainly use other fonts you have.

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zhmCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{ipaexm.ttf}
\setCJKsansfont{ipaexg.ttf}
\begin{document}

現在、\TeX{} システムの日本語化を進めているが、現時点で一応の動作が可能となった。

\textsf{現在、\TeX{} システムの日本語化を進めているが、現時点で一応の動作が可能となった。}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately, `zhmCJK` is not preinstalled in TeX Live or MiKTeX. You need to follow the instructions in the document to installed this package.

Comment: Running pdflatex on this examples results in a "font not found" problem.      
    mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for zhm280.  
    mktexpk: perhaps zhm280 is missing from the map file.  
    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file zhm280): Font zhm280 at 600 not found  Don't know wether this warning is relevant or not:

Comment: The warning is:  `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file Unicode.sfd): cannot open SFD file for reading`

Comment: @stl: It seems that you have not properly installed the package. It is necessary to install the modified `texfonts.map` and new `zhmCJK.map` in `$TEXMF/fonts/map/fontname/`. And the `Unicode.sfd` is a part of `ttfutils` package, you should install that package via TeX Live Manager if you haven't.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Installing `ttfutils` worked! Is it needed if I go via the `latex`+`dvipdfmx` route?

Comment: @stl: I guess you don't need that for dvipdfmx. Anyway, I always use a full scheme of TeX Live.

Comment: I've tested it with `ttfutils` removed and `dvipdfmx` failed with similar "font not found" problems. I'll try to test the `zhmCJK-test.tex` file that comes with the package using the fonts that I have and report back.  By the way, the `ttfutils` package is only in TeXLive but not in the CTAN archive.